# Is there a way to exclude a particular term from elastic search highlights?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying out a query in elastic search(version 6.0) where I have a base query and on top of that, I have filters applied to narrow down the search. It is as follows:

```
GET target_index/_search
{
  "from": {start},
  "size": {offset},
  "_source": [
    "id",
    "name",
    "email",
    "company",
    "created_at",
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            { "terms":{"name.raw": ["test","test2"] }},
            { "terms":{"email.raw": ["test@test.com","test2@test.com"] }} 
          ]
        }
      },
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "test",
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "*":{
        "type":"plain"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Current result -

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1.90374,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "index_name",
        "_id": "my_id",
        "_score": 1.90374,
        "_source": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "test", 
          "email": "test@test.com",
          "company": "test company"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "name.raw": [
            "<em>test</em>"
          ],
          "name": [
            "<em>test</em>"
          ],
          "company": [
            "<em>test</em> company"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Desired result -

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1.90374,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "index_name",
        "_id": "my_id",
        "_score": 1.90374,
        "_source": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "test", 
          "email": "test@test.com",
          "company": "test company"
        },
        "highlight": {
          "company": [
            "<em>test</em> company"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here, in the highlights in the desired result, I don't want the data for "name" and "name.raw". This field should not be searched only for this particular query , so I cannot disable the field entirely from searching.

I have a lot of terms and cannot specify every term to include in the query. Is there a way to exclude only a few fields from query search?

related ES doc -
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/index.html

Comment: Can you specify the docs, the current response, and the desired response?

Comment: @JoeSorocin Edited the question with relevant data. Let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *excluding*  certain fields, you could *include* only those that you need:

```json
{
  "query": {
    ...
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "company":{          <---
        "type":"plain"
      }
    }
  }
}
```